# Docker in Vagrant issuing : Warning: Connection refused. Retrying

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vagrant

I've been try to enable ssh access for Docker's containers running in Vagrant. I'm almost there. However, I keep getting errors when I run Vagrant up.

Here is my Vagrant file:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "app" do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "./Docker"
      d.cmd = ["/sbin/init", "--enable-insecure-key"]
      d.has_ssh = true
    end
  end
  config.ssh.username = "root"
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "./insecure_key"
end
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
# Unsecure key
FROM phusion/baseimage

RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh
RUN /usr/sbin/enable_insecure_key

#ADD /home/renato/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/id_rsa.pub
#RUN cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f /tmp/id_rsa.pub

# Ubuntu

FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Tyler Cipriani, tyler@tylercipriani.com

# Download and install php, nginx, and supervisor, hey, just linux for a change!
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y php5-fpm nginx supervisor

# Setup config files
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD ./nginx/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD ./supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ADD ./php-fpm/php-fpm.conf /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

# Shared volume
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
VOLUME ["/var/www"]

# Default command for container, start supervisor
CMD ["supervisord", "--nodaemon"]
USER root

# Expose port 80 of the container
EXPOSE 80
```

The ssh key I got from here.

https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/services/sshd/keys/insecure_key

Error in my screen:
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is your host system? Mac OS or some Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have two [`FROM`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) directives in your Dockerfile, two different docker images will be built. It seems vagrant sees only the last one (`FROM ubuntu:latest`) which does not have any ssh service.

As the [phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/Dockerfile#L1) is itself built from `ubuntu:14.04` and as having 2 different docker images is certainly not your goal in this case, you don't need to have that second `FROM` instruction in your Dockerfile. Just remove it and give it a try.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work. In the end I realised Docker+Vagrant don't mean to be accessed via ssh. I wrote a post of how I set that up in the end http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/dev-environment-with-docker-and-vagrant-on-ubuntu/.. Thanks again!

Comment: it is meant to be optionally accessed with ssh, see the [Vagrant documentation](http://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-docker-dev-environments.html#toc_4) or [this blog article](http://www.kodama.gr/2015/05/09/building-a-vagrant-ready-docker-image/)